# app.user.username in twig returns unable to add global

Tags: authentication, symfony, twig

as per the documentation:

```
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#retrieving-the-user-object
```

I am trying to use twig to check to see if the user is authenticated

when i put in my twig templates:

```
{{ app.user.username }}
```

I get the error

```
LogicException: Unable to add global "app" as the runtime or the extensions have already been initialized.
```

**EDIT:** Please find as per below the composer.json contents

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.1.*",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*@dev",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "kriswallsmith/assetic": "1.1.*@dev",
        "doctrine/data-fixtures": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web"
    }
}
```

Comment: I would update your vendors and clear your cache. Something is wonky. AFAIK, the only way that can happen is if you have a Twig Extension and you used `addGlobal('app', 'some value');`

Comment: Are you using such a non-Sensiolab bundle? Which version do you use exactly? Can you post your composer.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard to answer to this question without more details.

First, please notice that there have been such a similar exception in the past, due to a `Symfony2.1` bug which has been solved with a recent release: [see here for more details](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/6174).

Then, notice that the error seems to be thrown in `addGlobal` function of class `Twig_Environment`. Did you installed such Twig Extension?

Without reading your `composer.json`, I can suggest to try to:

1. Clear the cache.
2. **update** the code in your `composer.json`, to avoid the presence of up to date bundles.
3. Create the `composer.phar`.
4. Then compile it to get the `composer.phar`.
5. `php composer.phar install` or `php composer.phar update`, whatever be your case.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The Composer.json is correct! Do you generate the composer.phar through the latest version of Composer? Does the update and the clearing of the cache helped?

Comment: [Here](http://share.ez.no/forums/ez-publish-5-forum-formerly-known-as-new-php-api/twig-fails) you can find a similar issue.